# Docker Swarm Cant Find the RDS Host

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-rds, docker-swarm

Am exploring the docker swam and the is my yml file

```
    backend:
        image: "<redacted>"
        ports:
            - '5000:5000'
        environment:
            - PORT=5000
            - DB_NAME=<redacted>
            - DB_USERNAME=<redacted>
            - DB_HOST=lower-database.<redacted>.ap-southeast-1.rds.amazonaws.com
            - DB_PASSWORD=<redacted>
        
        deploy:
            replicas: 1
            placement:
                constraints:
                - "node.role==worker"
            update_config:
                parallelism: 1
                delay: 10s
                order: start-first
```

The stack gets deployed fine but the container throws an error as

```
ConnectionError [SequelizeConnectionError]: getaddrinfo EAI_AGAIN lower-database.<redacted>.ap-southeast-1.rds.amazonaws.com
```

**What I have checked?**

1. The RDS is in the same VPC as the Swarm Manager and Worker Node
2. The swam manager and nodes are able to reach to the RDS over telnet
3. The nslookup with the RDS address is also working fine
4. The psql cli is also able to connect to RDS with the same hostname and user creds
5. The env values are getting injected correctly and verified with container inspect

Any idea what might be going wrong?
Am not creating any network explicitly, all is default.

nslookup output:

```
ubuntu@SwamManager:~$ nslookup lower-database.<redacted>.ap-southeast-1.rds.amazonaws.com
Server:     127.0.0.53
Address:    127.0.0.53#53

Non-authoritative answer:
Name:   lower-database.<redacted>.ap-southeast-1.rds.amazonaws.com
Address: 10.0.150.216
Name:   lower-database.c5tdd8hk3ruj.ap-southeast-1.rds.amazonaws.com
Address: 2406:<redacted>:<redacted>:<redacted>:<redacted>:<redacted>:<redacted>
```

Comment: Got the answer from https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60946944/docker-service-in-swarm-cannot-connect-to-aws-rds-when-a-port-is-published?rq=2 Context: Subnets were overlapping